# Laravel artisan schedule:run running every minute on every install

Tags: php, linux, laravel, cron

I have a VPS with 60 of the same Laravel apps for different regions. Every minute I can see using the `htop` command that on all of my installs the php command `artisan schedule:run` fires. As I have so many install it's actually causing my CPU to be at almost a constant 100% usage.

I have 1 cron set to run daily;

**Cron Entry**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
   $schedule->command('sitemape:generate')
         ->daily();
}
```

**Handler**

```
public function handle(){
    SitemapGenerator::create(config('app.url'))
        ->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));
}
```

I tried to comment out this function but it still looks like the `artisan schedule:run` will fire. Is there anyway for me to dig deeper to see what's actually running and how to stop it?

[image]

Comment: Is your cron entry right? Like "* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1" whats happening if you manually run the artisan schedule:run command?

Comment: The path looks correct running the command I get `no scheduled commands are ready to run.`

Comment: Try to change the schedule command to everyMinute and type the command manually again.

Comment: @RobinGillitzer That worked got the following; `Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.2' 'artisan' sitemape:generate > '/dev/null' 2>&1`

Comment: I've just noticed the command is `sitemape` with an `e` on the end which I think is a typo. Looking at my function could this be causing it to fail & re-run?

Comment: It could be. Can you show your cron entry?

Comment: When you executed it manually the function worked correct? Can you show your cron entry (not the command handle)?